# Android show Tweets

Tags: android

hi
i need to show the tweets from twitter ,no posting , i have the keys , username password
.What is the steps for retrieveing the tweets from twitter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll want to choose how you need to download the twitter feed. Twitter has a couple of different types of ways you can access the feed. The most common way to do it would just a one-time access of the XML feed. They do have a [Streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api) if you might be interested in that. For accessing that, you might want to use an existing project like [TweetStream4J](http://techxplorer.com/2010/08/02/exploring-tweetstream4j/). Even if you're using the regular method, I've used [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/) and it is pretty solid.

Twitter4J is probably well-suited for your needs, but in case you want to write your own Twitter wrapper...

Twitter also has different feeds, e.g., the public timeline, the friends timeline, the list goes on... you need to select which of these you want to access. When most people login, they see their friends timeline.

Also, each timeline can be returned in different formats: for example: RSS, Atom, JSON, and Twitter's own XML format. From here, your approach can vary depending on what your needs are. JSON and XML are probably the most general routes to take for accessing the timeline. You'll need to choose which file format you'll use and an accompanying library which can decode that file format (or write one yourself).

If you take the XML route, you'll probably want to look at using SAX or DOM to decode the response. If you take the JSON route, you'll likely want to check out GSON.

Comment: Twitter constructor is deprecated

Comment: It says there in the source code that you should be using TwitterFactory.getInstance() to get Twitter objects. You should read the JavaDoc (http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Twitter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the information you will need about the Twitter API: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to fetch your tweets on android, then there's the twitter4j API.
It is in Java, should integrate nicely. I've heard it is not officially supported, but does work.
Link: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg09931.html

Comment: I found it but the twitter constructor is deprecated